# WSO2 - EI server startup isues

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am getting below error while starting EI server. Can you please let me know if anything is missed here.

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\WSO2\6.3.0\bin\..
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.server.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:66)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)
```

I had added a different value to CARBON_HOME but it is overriding with another value.

```
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\bin>set CARBON_HOME=C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0
 
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\bin>echo %CARBON_HOME%
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0
```

After running intergrator.bat, it overrides CARBON_HOME value.

```
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\bin>echo %CARBON_HOME%
C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\63AA0C~1.0\bin\..
```

Answer (score 0):

The part of the stack trace that says...

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.server.Main
```

... means that the code is trying to find a class `org.wso2.carbon.server.Main` but that it can't find it.

Java classes are typically held in `.class` files and/or `jar` files. You tell `java` where to find the appropriate jars and classes files by specifying a classpath.

So, the problem you have is that the required jars or classes can't be found on the classpath. It may be that the classpath is wrong or that the jars are missing.

The environment variable `CARBON_HOME` path looks like it might be wrong. I would remove the `\bin\..` part which is unnecessary and could cause issues.

You might also try to set that variable to the full path `C:\Program Files\...`, rather than the short-form DOS path `C:\PROGRA~1\...`.

And look inside the directory to confirm that the JAR files are there (and where they are) and that whatever command file you're running has the right classpath, so it can find those jars.